# How do I make my "Lingo" game in python 3.5 work?

Tags: python-3.x

The game is slightly different from the lingo, in the sense that any wordlength can be used. How can I make my program print a ? when the letter is in the word but not on the correct spot? and how do I make it print the actually letter if the letter is in the correct spot? e.g the word is "tank" and the user entered "town" it should print "t--?" I got everything working until the point where I have to make my code output characters other than "-"
(The words are in dutch, but that shouldnt make any difference)

```
import random
wordlist = ["hond", "haas", "neus", "peer","fruit", "laptop","raam","computer", "python", "hakan", "akkas", "mohammed", "amine", "school","informatica"]
word = random.choice(wordlist)
print("Your secret word has ", len(word), "letters")
while True:
    guessword = input("Guess the word:")
    if len(Guessword) != len(word): print("type a word with", len(word),"letters")
    elif guessword == word: break
    elif guessword != word:
        if guessword != word:  print("-" * len(word))
print("Congratulations, you guessed the word correctly!")
```

I also have to make the game tell you how many turns it took you to guess the word as well as implementing a score system based off time.

EDIT: Has to be as compact as possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way of doing it using `enumerate`:

```
import random
wordlist = ["hond", "haas", "neus", "peer","fruit", "laptop","raam","computer", "python", "hakan", "akkas", "mohammed", "amine", "school","informatica"]
# 'word' hardcoded for testing
word = "tank" #random.choice(wordlist)
print("Your secret word has ", len(word), "letters")
while True:
    guessword = input("Guess the word:")
    if len(guessword) != len(word): print("type a word with", len(word),"letters")
    elif guessword == word: break
    elif guessword != word:
        for position, letter in enumerate(guessword):
            if letter == word[position]:
                print(letter, end="")
            elif letter not in word:
                print("-", end="")
            else:
                print("?", end="")
        print("")
print("Congratulations, you guessed the word correctly!")
```

Testing:

```
$ python3.5 word_game.py 
Your secret word has  4 letters
Guess the word:town
t--?
Guess the word:tans
tan-
Guess the word:tank
Congratulations, you guessed the word correctly!
```

Comment: Thanks, it helped a lot! But how do I implement a score system and tell the player how many turns it took them to guess the word?

Comment: @MohammedElKahtaoui Add a counter value outside (before) the loop, increment it in `elif guessword != word:` and print it after `print("Congratulations, you guessed the word correctly!")`

Comment: Okay I implemented the score, and implemented a line where the code asks for the player's name. How do I make a self-updating list of highscores (max 5 names in the highscore list)